# How we Fix the APT repository errors Debian os

Tags: linux, debian, docker, update, repository

How to fix Fix the APT repository errors I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch), how can i fix this update error ?and import the Docker GPG key?

```
root@test:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Err:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 111.73.1113.145 90]
Get:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease [44.8 kB]
Ign:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Err:5 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch Release
  404  Not Found
Err:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7PB0A8C2F192FFDM
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org stretch/updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7PB0A8C2F192FFDM

root@test:~# apt-get install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 tree amd64 1.7.0-5
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tree/tree_1.7.0-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have this sources.list

```
root@test:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main

# deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stretch all
# deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stretch all
```

Any short of help would be appreciated .

Comment: getting this same issue when trying to do `apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx` as part of a docker build as well.    

following for resolution

Answer (score 6):

You can try the archive repos, like this:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib 
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib 
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main non-free contrib
```

Answer (score 2):

## Upgrade to a supported distribution.

[Stretch is end of life](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Stretch). It has been end of life for nearly a year. You're getting the errors because it has been removed from the distribution mirrors.

Comment: How to do the fix , without upgrade ?

Comment: Upgrade. Running wildly out of date code is a huge security risk.

Comment: Without upgrade: get the answer of @vidarlo. I use the local server based on debian Etch, too. I do because it is a local net with five Apple iMacs running MacOS X SnowLeopard with a DTP system. The server and the iMacs will work until their death. In a similar studio they are upgrading each month, their sunk cost are five times mines. Keep your debian clean, no open ports, use firewall or proxy, and you can use it until the physical death of hardware. The main security risk stays between the keyboard and a seat.